# FileSystemWatcher - Creating a new file when the FileSystemWatcher is watching, and then trying to access it gives me an error

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, file, user-interface

I am a beginner in C# WPF, and I am trying to create an app, which uses DataTable and writes this DataTable to an XML file using DataTable.WriteXML() method. Then the XML file is being read by the DataGrid from the ListView (selectedList).

```
 private void refreshDataGrid(DataGrid dataGridName, ListView selectedList, string path)
    {
        FileStream file;
        //check if the item from ListView is selected
        if (selectedList.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            try
            {
                file = File.Open(path + "\\" + selectedList.SelectedItem.ToString() + ".xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
                return;
            }
            //clear the defaultData DataSet so it doesn't have any content
            defaultData.Tables.Clear();
            //read XML file
            defaultData.ReadXml(file);
            file.Close();
            dataGridName.ItemsSource = defaultData.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
```

DataGrid is editable by the user and when he does Edit the content, It is saved to an XML file, and then FileWatcher is watching for changes in Last Access to the file, so when the content of a file is changing, the datagrid will update.

```
FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new();
private void CreateFileWatcher(string path)
    {
        fileWatcher.Path = path;
        fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.FileName;
        fileWatcher.Filter = "*.xml";
        fileWatcher.Changed += FileWatcher_Changed;
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    
    // Event for filewatcher throws an Exception
    
    private void FileWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() =>
         {
             try
             {
                 refreshDataGrid(dataGridName, userListView, path);
             }
             catch(Exception)
             {
                 return;
             }
         }));
    }
```

So the issue is, when i create a NEW XML FILE while the app is running, and then user opens this file in a DataGrid and edits a field in the DataGrid, the data is saved to an XML file as it should be, and FileWatcher is Invoked, so when the FileWatcher is trying to refresh the Datagrid I get this message:

> Could not find UIElementAutomationPeer.cs
> You need to find
> UIElementAutomationPeer.cs to view the source for the current call
> stack frame System.ArgumentNullException: „Value cannot be null.
> Arg_ParamName_Name”.
> Unhandled exception of type „System.ArgumentNullException” in PresentationCore.dll
> Value cannot be null.

When i create an XML file, and restart the app, everything works normally. Also when the file was created before launching the app, FileWatcher is working fine. I guess newly created files (during app runtime) are not updated to the app itself, and it needs to refresh the UI but I don't know how. My FileWatcher is also global, so maybe that could be an issue, or should I refresh the FileWatcher somehow? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I think there is a problem while creating a file in my program, probably the app wants to use the same file twice or can't access it, here is the code:

```
private void saveTableToXML()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ((DataView)dataGridName.ItemsSource).ToTable();
        try
        {
            FileStream file = File.Create(path + "\\.xml");  
            dt.WriteXml(file, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema,false);
            file.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
       
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception message and call stack.  That error seems like something an IDE would show when it doesn't have PDBs loaded.  Not the actual exception.

Comment: Call Stack: PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Automation.Peers.UIElementAutomationPeer.FromElement(System.Windows.UIElement element) Line 70 C#

Comment: Exception Message: {"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'element')"} System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: Which line of code above throws that exception?  You can edit your question to put it in the code like `//this line throws the exception`.  Better than commenting so all can see it in the question.  I'd also suggest setting a breakpoint in `refreshDataGrid` and stepping through the method line by line so you can verify it's doing what you think it is.

Comment: I did debug refeshDataGrid but it works fine till the last line of code, I edited the question now

Comment: So this line `dataGridName.ItemsSource = defaultData.Tables[0].DefaultView;` throws the exception?  That would've been my guess.  Inspect those values, it's probably not what you want.  Maybe there is no table, or default view?

Comment: No, the exception is thrown by FileSystemWatcher function somehow , the ItemsSource is being changed succesfully

Comment: Ok, what line throws?  If you have a debugger attached it will highlight the line of code.  Is it that try catch block you have in the event?  I'd get rid of that, or do something useful with the exception.

Comment: FileWatcher_Changed() throws an exception, to be clear: If I delete refreshDataGrid() from FileWatcher_Changed() it works ok cause It does nothing basically after the deletion

Comment: That means some line in `refreshDataGrid` is throwing.  We need that line.  Or it's the the way you invoke it.  You could simply do `this.BeginInvoke`.  You can also check `InvokeRequired` to see if you're on the GUI thread already.

Comment: I added a messagebox after refreshDataGrid() in FileWatcher_Changed() and the MessageBox is showing, so it means that the refreshDataGrid() is not throwing I guess

Comment: My initial thought is that the file is being read while it's still being written. The file watcher is listening to a whole bunch of things. If I understand correctly, it's the same app writing and reading the file, so I don't understand the need for a file watcher at all. Why not just signal internally what's going on? Also, log to a viewer (the console?) what's happening instead of using the debugger.

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure  that a file watcher will raise it's event _before_ the changed file is closed. As a test. Put in a slight delay and see what happens.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that your program creates a row in a datatable, writes the datatable to disk, uses a fsw to detect the file being written, loads it from disk and displays it in a datatable? Are you aware that you can leave the disk and the fsw out of it completely and get the row to show in the grid with just one line of code? Passing data between different parts of your program by writing them to disk and reading them back is *ludicrous*..

Comment: I added my code for creating a new XML file in my app, is it possible that I didn't close the file properly?